# WAMPSERVER - Only upgrade PHP Version from 5.4.3 to 5.5.4

Tags: php, wampserver, php-5.5

Can i upgrade the PHP version under wampserver instead of whole?
Because current latest version of wampserver gives 5.4.3 version, but the latest version of php is 5.5.4.

How can i upgrade it?

EDIT :

Wampserver provides either 5.4.3 or older version. What I'm trying to do is Download latest PHP version from php's official site and than copy that into the wampserver. So that i can select toggle between newer and older version.

This is how wampserver control panel will look like after adding a version of php
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pOx3.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/joSf3.png

**I GOT MY ANSWER :**

A type of handler is required to handle  PHP 5.5, which is not built current handler supports 5.4 < versions. The handler is provided by IONCUBE.

This is what i found -

"*Ioncube for PHP5.5 is not yet released as of 13/09/2013, they say they are waiting for PHP 5.5 to become stable and secure and hosting providers to adopt PHP 5.5 before they release their upgrade. They comment that it can take a year or more for hosting companies to adopt new versions of PHP and this I guess is their schedule.*"

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly !!

Thank you all for active commenting and help!

Comment: Why not? Have you tried?

Comment: Yes i followed this : http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113423,113435#msg-113435
whether it not old or not well written or i didn't get it properly.

Comment: You didnt mention anything about IONCUBE in your question??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this thread on the wampserver.com forum site

[HOW TO MANUALLY INSTALL A NEW RELEASE OF PHP INTO THE WAMP ENVIRONMENT](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116940,117978#msg-117978)

Comment: This is the closest answer i can get.

Comment: How to install a new Apache yourself http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,118264,118276#msg-118276

Comment: Thanks! I'll check this! Will reply back

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have checked your provided link and followed steps. My new php version is displaying in system tray -- But it is not activating successfully. I am trying to install PHP5.5.15 version while currently have version 5.3.5

Comment: Thats a large step forwards in PHP versions. If PHP5.3.5 which was compiled with VC6 runs with the Apache version you have installed then the Apache is also compiled with VC6. PHP5.5.15 is compiled with VC11 (VS2012) and will only run with an Apache compiled with VC11. You are going to have to install a newer version of Apache as well as PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the versions of PHP addons on [wamps page](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Where you can download and install them from.

Comment: Except that version does not exists!!